# Sort on a grouped column cognos

Tags: sorting, report, grouping, reporting, cognos

I've looked at a few ways to do this and I am unfortunately coming up short.

I have a list report in Cognos on which i have grouped some but not all columns. I would like to sort by customer account however i believe my groupings aren't letting me.

Columns:

Customer Account (Grouped)
Customer Name (Grouped)
Order Reference (Grouped)
Product Code
Sales Document Number (Grouped)
Order Date
Required Date
Despatch Date
Quantity Despatched
Despatch Mode
Despatch Price (Grouped)

The table shows the customers orders, what they have purchased and the collective price.

I would like to sort by the customer orders (grouped) column.

Thanks in advance

Will

Comment: You've contradicted yourself. In the beginning you said "I would like to sort by customer account..." but later you say that you want to sort by customer orders. Which is it?

Comment: ah apologies

I would like to sort by Customer Account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this i was fortunate that we did not require the grouping in the end and this was only a nice to have.

Thanks to anyone who logs onto this in order to help but the problem is sorted.

Thanks

Will